# Google's Icon Legality

Tags: google, legal, icon

I'm creating a homepage for all the computers within my company. We're a small business so we're using Google Apps. I've designed a very simple site that will be only accessible with an authorised Google account.

Below is a screenshot of the page with all the necessary links people within my company will need. Is there any legal issues with using the icons of the products within my own page, even when I'm not profiting form them in any way?

[image: The Homepage]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of policies:

[Permissions](https://www.google.com/intl/en/permissions/).

If your issue isn't covered in these, I suggest you [Contact Them](https://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/) via email.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a quicklauncher shortcuts page, I would not worry much about what google is going to think.  Chances are that even if you were violating any policy of theirs, they would not care because its not for a commercial purpose and points your users to their products.   If you want to play it super safe (compliance paranoia) then replace the icons with ones created by third party designers.  You can find similar mail, and apps icons which your users will recognize on sites like iconfinder and deviantart.